# Scratch org creation hangs

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, cumulusci

In the past weeks we are observing a lot of issues when creating a scratch org. It seems `cumulusci` or `sfdx` hangs during the scratch org creation:

```
Executing command: cci org scratch dev master                                                                                                      
master is configured for use                                                                                                                                     
------------------------------                                                                                                                                   
Executing command: cci flow run dev_org_with_test_data --org master                                                                                     
2021-09-08 16:08:18: Fetching from GitHub: *** @ main (***)        
2021-09-08 16:08:18: ============================================================                                                                                
2021-09-08 16:08:18: Initializing flow: FlowCoordinator (dev_org_with_test_data)                                                                                 
2021-09-08 16:08:18: create a new dev org and upload test data                                                                                                   
2021-09-08 16:08:18: ============================================================                                                                                
2021-09-08 16:08:18:                                                                                                                                             
2021-09-08 16:08:18: Verifying and refreshing credentials for the specified org: master.                                                                                 
2021-09-08 16:08:18:                                                                                                                                             
2021-09-08 16:08:18: Verifying and refreshing credentials for the specified org: master.                                                                         
2021-09-08 16:08:18: Creating scratch org with command: sfdx force:org:create  -f orgs/dev_mlt.json -w 120 -n --durationdays 3 -a business
```

The issue occurs randomly with `cumulusci 3.35.0` with Python `3.7` and `sfdx 7.110`.

---

*edit*

Here the `orgs/dev_mlt.json`:

```
{
  "orgName": "mlt - Dev Org",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": [
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "StateAndCountryPicklist",
    "FieldAuditTrail",
    "DefaultWorkflowUser",
    "WorkThanksPref"
  ],
  "language": "en_US",
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "workDotComSettings": {
      "enableWorkThanksPref": true,
      "enableProfileSkills": true
  },
    "chatterSettings": {
      "enableChatter": true
    },
    "userManagementSettings": {
      "enableNewProfileUI": true
    },
    "securitySettings": {
      "enableAdminLoginAsAnyUser": true,
      "sessionSettings": {
        "forceRelogin": false
      }
    },
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    },
    "emailAdministrationSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Upgraded to cci `3.43`, Python `3.9`, node `16.9`, and sfdx `7.116.3`. The issue still randomly occurs.

Comment: what's your `orgs/dev_mlt.json` like? In terms of features, edition, and settings. Have you noticed it only for `dev_mlt` or for all other org configurations?

Comment: We don't have other org configurations. The json was not changed in the past weeks.

`{"orgName": "mlt - Dev Org","edition": "Enterprise","features":["ContactsToMultipleAccounts","StateAndCountryPicklist","FieldAuditTrail","DefaultWorkflowUser","WorkThanksPref"],"language": "en_US",}`

Comment: it's best to [edit] your question with that kind of info since it looks much better there than squished in comments! Just looking to see what features/settings are there to see if it can be replicated.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves thank you, I noticed and edited.

Comment: also wasn't able to create Scratch Org today for around 2-3 hours. Team had similar issues last week. Was getting socket timeout randomly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sporadic errors occurring in the recent weeks are likely due to this known issue which was created around that time period:

[sfdx force:org:create getting failed with an error - Socket timeout occurred while listening for results](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001U1BhQAK)

It's mentioned as an "intermittent error". I presume that's why cumulusci is presenting as "hanging" as the issue occurs during the sfdx cli command (`sfdx force:org:create`)

The current workaround, listed in the known issue, is to re-try the command.

However, there's more customer information in the [github issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1149) that was created for the same error. It's possible the org may still be getting created if you check your Dev Hub's active scratch orgs.

Comment: This should be fixed with the latest sfdx release.

Comment: Apparently, it is not fixed in `sfdx-cli/7.129.0 linux-x64 node-v15.0.1`, still getting `Socket timeout occurred while listening for results` both in terminal and from IDE.